# How to handle heavy message load in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-integration

External module sends thousands of messages to the message broker. Each message has a TimeToLive property equal to 5 secs. Another module should consume and process ALL the messages.

From Spring Integration documentation I found that Staged Event-driven
architecture (consumers) respond better to significant spikes in the load.

My current implementation uses EDA (even Driven Architecture), e.g.

```
<si:channel id="inputChannel"/>

<!-- get messages from PRESENCE_ENGINE queue -->    
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter" 
    channel="inputChannel" destination="sso" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  
    max-concurrent-consumers="1" auto-startup="true" acknowledge="transacted" extract-payload="true"/>

<si:service-activator id ="activatorClient" input-channel="inputChannel" ref="messageService" method="processMessage"/> 

<bean id="messageService" class="com.my.messaging.MessageService"/>

<bean id="sso" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="SSO" />
</bean>
```

Obviously by heavy load,e.g. incoming thousands of messages, processMessage() can take longer than 5 secs. and the MessageService may not handle all the messages.

My ideas are following:

1. Modify processMessage() so that the message instead of being
   processed is only stored in MongoDB.  Then I could process the
   messages in a separate task independently. In such a scenario
   MongoDB would serve as a CACHE.
2. Use a large number of consumers (SEDA model). The inputChannel is a direct channel.
3. Process the messages asynchronously, e.g. inputChannel is a queue channel and the messages are processed asynchronously.

Before making the decision I would like to ask you which scenario is more effective. Perhaps Scenarios 2) and 3) provides a mechanism for meeting my requirement that ALL messages should be processed, even by heavy loads.

**EDIT:**

I already implemented scenario 2 where I keep sending 1000 messages per second.
This is the statistics how many messages were missing with varying parameters:

max-concurrent-consumers ; TimeToLive=5secs.; Idle-consumer-limit; # of sent messages; # of received messages

```
 10 ; Yes ; 1   ; 1001 ; 297
100 ; Yes ; 1   ; 1001 ; 861
150 ; Yes ; 1   ; 1001 ; 859
300 ; Yes ; 1   ; 1001 ; 861
300 ; No  ; 1   ; 1001 ; 860
300 ; No  ; 100 ; 1001 ; 1014
300 ; No  ; 50  ; 1001 ; 1011
```

It seems idle-consumer-limit creates consumers more aggresively than max-concurrent consumers. Is this is a good approach to use idle-consumer-limit in such a scenario?

This is my config files for sender/consumer:

```
<!-- SENDER  
Keep Alive Sender sends messages to backup server -->    

<si:channel id="sendToChannel"/>
<si:channel id="presChannel"/>

<si:inbound-channel-adapter id="senderEntity" channel="sendToChannel" method="sendMessage"> 
    <bean class="com.ucware.ucpo.sso.cache.CacheSender"/>
    <si:poller fixed-rate="${sender.sendinterval}"></si:poller>
</si:inbound-channel-adapter>    

<si:router id="messageRouter" method="routeMessage" input-channel="sendToChannel">
    <bean class="com.ucware.ucpo.sso.messaging.MessageRouter"/>
</si:router>

<!-- Subscriber to a channel dispatcher, Send messages to JMS -->
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter  explicit-qos-enabled="${jms.qos.enabled}" time-to-live="${jms.message.lifetime}" 
    channel="presChannel" connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination="pres" extract-payload="false"/>

<bean id="pres" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="PRES" />
</bean>


<!-- RECEIVER -->

<si:channel id="receiveChannel"/>

<!-- get messages from PRES queue -->    
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter" 
    channel="receiveChannel" destination="presence" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  idle-consumer-limit="50" 
    max-concurrent-consumers="300" auto-startup="true" acknowledge="transacted" extract-payload="true"/>

<si:service-activator id ="activatorClient" input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="messageService" method="processMessage"/> 


<bean id="messageService" class="com.cache.MessageService"/>
```

Comment: You seem to have an odd combination of requirements. A limited time to live, combined with required delivery is going to give you problems. Is there some reason why you can't remove the time to live? Or configure the broker to put them on to a persistent queue?

Comment: Indeed, this is a requirement we could omit. But we need to be sure ALL messages are consumed. My initial tests in Scenario 2 showed for 1000 messages sent within a minute only 860 are received (with time-to-live on and off).

Comment: That sounds odd ... message brokers should all be able to ensure that no messages are missed.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can try to play with `max-concurrent-consumers` property. As you see, in your case `1` is really not enough.
You should investigate why your `MessageService` is so slowly.
Any other cases looks like overhead, because JMS is already persistent and have async nature - queue-based.
If it doesn't help, so use `<queue>` channel with presistence `MessageStore`, e.g. MongoDB

Comment: I raised the number of max-concurent consumers and it helped but only to a certain extend (see my update). +1 for suggestion.